# Register automation object

Tags: delphi, com

I have an application with an automation object.
In the delphi IDE I can register it via the button "register type library".
As an alternative I can use codegear's tregsvr.

But how should I register the application when it's installed on other computers?
Should the setup include the tregsvr.exe? Am I allowed to contribute the tregsvr.exe?
Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 7):

Windows has a `regsvr32.exe` which is able to register DLLs (or OCXs). If your server is an EXE you should be able to register it using the command line switch `/REGSERVER`.

Comment: Or If you use InnoSetup you can do this with "regserver" flag.

Comment: Hi, I already tried this.
I have no dll (or ocx), I got a tlb..
When I try to register the tlb with the command "regsvr32 blabla.tlb" I get an error which says something like "Module is not compatible with the windows version you want to execute. Check if the module is compatible with an x86-Version oder x64-Version of regsrv32.exe"
But when I run "tregsvr -u blabla.tlb' it works.

Comment: I forgot to say:
I also tried to register the application via /REGSERVER
On the development machine it works, but on a test-machine I get an EOleSysError (Error accessing OLE registration)

Comment: /REGSERVER works - I tried to run it without administrator privilegs - execute as admin worked.

Comment: Yeah, you definitely need admin rights to register a com server.

Comment: *Power User* privileges should suffice.

Comment: you don't need admin rights to register a com server. use "tregsvr -c appname"

Answer (score 0):

This mechanism is called *self-registration*, so your COM server library performs registration itself.

```
RegSvr32 yours.dll
RegSvr32 /u yours.dll
```

Actually, along with this, there are lot of Windows built-in registration behaviours, all of them are simple, you only need to list your file eg. in RegisterDlls INF section. Those are merely a calls to DllRegisterServer and DllUnregisterServer functions